# How to write an async function to import data from from all `.csv` files using `Promise.all`?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my current code, I need to replace the names of the hardcoded files with a function to import data from all CSV files under the `data/CSV` folder.

```js
const importTables = [
    "Macquarie University course.csv",
    "Australia National University courses.csv",
    "UTS courses.csv",
    "UNSW courses.csv",
    "Western University of Sydney courses.csv"
  ]
const Importdatamultiplefiles = async function () {
    await Promise.all(importTables.map(CourseInformation => importdata(CourseInformation, courseParams.TableName)));
    return;
  }

Importdatamultiplefiles();
```

Comment: Why not `return await Promise.all(`…`);`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon if you suggest that, take it one step further and remove `await`. Same thing

Comment: [`fs.promises.opendir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_opendir_path_options) or readdir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the list of csv files you can use the [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) package. To install:

```
npm i glob
```

Then define a async function to generate the list of csv files:

```js
var glob = require("glob")

async function getAllCSVs(path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    glob(path+"/*.csv", {}, function (er, files) {
      if (er) reject(er);
      else resolve(files);
    }
  });
}
```

Then in your code add

```js
try {
  importTables = await getAllCSVs("data/CSV");
  // rest of the code
}
catch(e) {
  // oops, error while getting list of csv files ...
}
```